# How to use variable as a match in saltstack mine.get

Tags: salt-stack, jinja2

I am trying to use a salt mine to get a list of network interfaces of all the minions with the same os as that of the minion on which the jinja template is rendered.

I am trying something like this:

```
{% set variable = grains['os'] %}     
{% set dict = salt['mine.get'('os:variable','network.interfaces','grain') %}
{% for i in dict : %}
    // do stuff here
```

But the problem is in the above salt will try to match os to the value "variable" not to the actual value of the variable.

Using `'os: {{ variable }}'` doesn't work too since `{{ x }}` just prints the value of variable x.

How can I match against the actual os in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try `+` to concatenate prefix and variable name:

```
{% set variable = grains['os'] %}     
{% set dict = salt['mine.get']('os:' + variable,'network.interfaces','grain') %}
{% for i in dict : %}
  # do stuff
{% endfor %}
```